# Deploying multiple copies of the same site to Azure easily

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-automation

I have a CMS that I intend to use for a number of websites on Azure.

I want to be able to create clones of the website easily and have them deployed to Azure.

Azure Automation was suggested as one possible solution, does this service fit my need?

Which Azure service should I use to do this?

Comment: Using web apps, cloud services or vms?

Comment: Azure Automation is **not** the solution you would want to implement for Continuous Integration / Delivery and auto deployments. In any case, your question is too broad to be answered. Please indicate a concrete and specific issue you are facing. Everything else is freely available on the Internet.

Comment: I'm going to edit your question which I hope makes it clearer. Please fix my edit if I'm incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to deploy multiple copies of a single website through Azure.

Two Azure services may fit your need.

- [Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-choose-me/)
  Supports scaling clones of the website. Cheaper than Cloud Services and is a great choice if you don't need complete control over the VMs that run your web apps, mobile app backends, API apps, etc.
- [Cloud Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-choose-me/) (specifically web roles)
  Cloud services allow you to deploy your ASP.NET website as a payload that you can then scale in/out either to a set amount of instances you want, based on traffic demand, or based on a queue of work items You have more control over the OS though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use web apps, then you can create an Azure Resource Manager template which will allow you to create a completely reproducible web app with each deployment. In your case, a CMS. Please see this link for an example with the web app content stored in github: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-arm-from-github-provision/. Web deploy can also be used as a deployment mechanism.

Once the template is authored you will be able to easily create clones of your website with the following powershell command:

```
New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-web-app-github-deploy/azuredeploy.json -siteName ExampleSite -hostingPlanName ExamplePlan -siteLocation "West US" -ResourceGroupName ExampleDeployGroup
```

Note that you can also use a local template with `-TemplateFile`.